# Retrieve Map data grouped by its values

Tags: c++

I have a map :

```
std::map<long, std::vector<Rule>> Rules;
```

Rule :

```
struct Rule
{
 int m_id= -1;
 std::wstring m_ruleName;
 double m_angleValue;
};
```

I want to get back all Rule values grouped in m_ruleName;

example :
map :

```
1->R{1,file1,90}
2->R{2,file2,80}
3->R{2,file1,80}
```

Expecting : output std::map output;

output

```
file1:1,3
file2:2
```

how can i do this with std::transform?

Try with my Transform :

```
std::transform(Rules.begin(), Rules.end(),             std::back_inserter(labelsInSettingsFile), [&](std::pair<long, std::vector<Rules>>& rule) {
    std::vector<long> labels;
    for (auto fileName : rule.second)
    {
        if (labelsInSettingsFile.find(fileName.m_positionName) != labelsInSettingsFile.end())
        {
            labelsInSettingsFile.at(fileName.m_positionName).push_back(rule.first);
            continue;
        }
        return std::make_pair(fileName.m_positionName, labels);
    }
    return std::make_pair<std::wstring, std::vector<long>>(L"", {});
});
```

Comment: Must it be `std::transform`? `for_each` or a ranged for would make more sense.

Comment: According to your map definition, same id is mapped to an array of rules. Are all the rules in this array have the same name?

Comment: there can be redundant values. But i need to get all keys  under a unique name